# Автоматическое выделение текста в поле при наведении курсора

Tags: javascript, css3, автоматизация, выделение-текста

Как сделать так, чтобы текст в input типа text при наведении курсора автоматически выделялся и, по возможности копировался, как это сделанно в https://iplogger.ru/ здесь, например, https://iplogger.ru/statistics/id=y67yh60aCe/tab=info/ или savepic.ru сразу после сохранения картинки?

Comment: на сайте в исходный код посмотрите, используется clipboard.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $auto_width = $('.auto-width');
$.each($auto_width, function(){
      $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
})// это что бы немного раздвинуть инпуты.
```

```css
input{border:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<input type="text" class="auto-width" readonly onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);document.execCommand('copy');" value="С уважением, команда bCool" />

<!-- input закрыт от прямого редактирования атрибутом readonly. -->
<!-- this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length); выделяет содержимое -->
<!-- execCommand('copy'); копирует выделенное в буфер -->
```